# Is there way to input a list to a Python program in the command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to pass a list as a parameter using the command line, for example:

```
$python example.py [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
```

I want the first list [1,2,3] to be first_list and [4,5,6] to be second_list. How can I do this?

Comment: Either use a string format or use some form of `eval` (extremely dangerous - this is user input!). So - use a string format of a list (`example.py 1,2,3 3,4,5`).

Comment: @ReutSharabani I cannot do that, the program will be tested as shown in my question.

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval`. `eval` is probably fine for a test program that only you will run.

Comment: This means you'll have to parse the input. If it's just a stringified list you may be able to use the `json` module on each of the arguments. I'm not sure about the security `literal_eval` offers so I'm not going to offer it :-)

Comment: You get args in `sys.argv`. You just have to parse them. Please don't ask people to do your homework.

Comment: There is an extended code example of using ast.literal_eval to pass lists, dicts and tuples to Python on the command line at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605631/passing-a-list-to-python-from-command-line, see answer by the-wolf.

Answer (score 1):

```
import ast
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
    try:
        print sum(ast.literal_eval(arg))
    except:
        pass
```

In command line:

```
   >>= python passListAsCommand.py "[1,2,3]"
    6
```

Be careful not to pass anything malicious to `literal_eval`.

Answer (score 1):

`[` might be a shell meta-character. You could drop `[]` as [@Reut Sharabani suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544938/is-there-way-to-input-a-list-to-a-python-program-in-the-command-line#comment52946716_32544938):

```
$ python example.py 1,2,3 4,5,6
```

It is easy to parse such format:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

def arg2int_list(arg):
    """Convert command-line argument into a list of integers.

    >>> arg2int_list("1,2,3")
    [1, 2, 3]
    """
    return list(map(int, arg.split(',')))

print(*map(arg2int_list, sys.argv[1:]))
# -> [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
def command_list():
    l = []
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        for i in sys.argv[1:]:
            l.append(i)
    return l
print(command_list())
```

In the command line

```
$ python3 test105.py 1,2,3 4,5,6
['1,2,3', '4,5,6']
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is trying to do, `'1,2,3'` is still a string (and not a list)