# python use shell command and send the output

Tags: python, shell, command-line

I have a python file name "a.py" and another python file name "b.py". I wanted to run a.py with command in b.py file and I use this codes below:

```
import os

def b():
    os.system("python a.py")
```

but a.py has a list name "list_exam" that I want to pass it to b.py through the command line code. I don't know how to pass it in a.py and how to get with command in b.py file.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to do this from the command line? importing would probably be much easier for this use case

Comment: in fact, my main command is os.system("python b.py -c configs/conf.json") and I want to send different config each time. @FlyingTeller

Comment: serialize/de-serialize? or just use modules... if you have json you can pass more list data in there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to call a Python script from another Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use shell commands to invoke other Python scripts, it is neither efficient nor scalable.

if `a.py`:

```
def do_somthing(param1, param2):
    ...
    list_exam = make_result()
    return list_exam

def main(config):
    do_something(config['param1'], config['param2'])
```

you can write `b.py` like this:

```
import a

def b():
    list_exam = a.do_something(config['param1'], config['param2'])
```

don't forget to create a `__init__.py` file in that dir.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use sys.argv to get command line parameters.
Take a look at this: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv

But, maybe your question is already answered here:
[Passing a List to Python From Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605631/passing-a-list-to-python-from-command-line)